# How to update this specific data in this user collection in mongodb?

Tags: performance, mongodb, stream

I need to do an update to a specific soldier in this user collection:

For example:

```
user: {
     myArmy : {
        money      : 100,
        fans       : 100,
        mySoldiers : [{
            _id        : ddd111bbb,
            mySkill   : 50,
            myStamina : 50,
            myMoral   : 50,
        },       
        {
            _id        : ddd111dd ,
            mySkill   : 50,
            myStamina : 50,
            myMoral   : 50,
        }],
     }
}
```

I want in my update query to do like the following:

```
conditions = { _id : user._id };

update =
            { 'myArmy.mySoldiers._id' : soldierId},
            {
                '$set': {
                    'myArmy.money'      : balanceToSet,
                    'myArmy.fans'       : fansToSet,
                    'myArmy.mySoldiers.$.skill': skillToSet,
                    'myArmy.mySoldiers.$.stamina': staminaToSet,
                    'myArmy.mySoldiers.$.moral': moralToSet
                }
            }
```

and this is the final query:

```
User.update(conditions, update, options, function(err){
     if (err) deferred.reject;
     stream.resume();
});
```

And the end result  if soldierId is 'ddd111bbb':

```
user: {
         myArmy : {
            money      : 200,
            fans       : 100,
            mySoldiers : [{
                _id        : ddd111bbb,
                mySkill   : 150,
                myStamina : 250,
                myMoral   : 50,
            },       
            {
                _id        : ddd111dd ,
                mySkill   : 50,
                myStamina : 50,
                myMoral   : 50,
            }],
         }
    }
```

Those skill, moral and stamina should change only on the specific soldier.
How do i get the $ to be the index number of this soldier, what is missing from the update query above?

Comment: This is all very pseudo. Why not actually "try something". A lot of what you are writing out is close, so why not go one more step further and write some real code? So what if it fails. That's how you learn.

Comment: Could not have been much of an effort. If this contained something that looked like a real code listing but was broken then I might be more helpful. As it is you seem scared to actually try anything, but by doing that you are running the risk of this looking like a *"Write my code for me"* question. Where that will not be very well received at all.

Comment: Little lost on the overall "intent". On one hand you want to match an "array" item and the general breakdown "seems" fine, but possibly there is something wrong in actual "update" statement assingment? ( show code please ). Also a bit unsure of what the purpose of setting the entries "outside of the array" are meant to "really" achieve in this context. So it would be nice if you took some time to actually explain "what data is already there" and "what the end result should look like". Honestly, if you don't have a mentor like this at work then they "suck". Be concise in what you ask.

Comment: Mostly noting that your "update" var is not an "array" and also you are not showing how it is applied in either `.update()` or `.findOneAndUpdate()` depending on what you really want to do here. The wider code context gives a much clearer picture. So please expand.

Comment: The 'User' is the User model not the user like if a find was applied...

Comment: If you see the above big announcment ( 10 millions questions asked...), a million of them were mine so please let me know if i wasn't specific enough in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i was looking for:

```
conditions = { _id : user._id , 'myArmy.mySoldiers._id' : soldierId};
                update = {
                    $set: {
                        'myArmy.balance': balanceToSet,
                        'myArmy.fans'   : fansToSet,
                        'myArmy.tokens' : tokensToSet,
                        'myArmy.mySoldiers.$.skill'  : skillToSet,
                        'myArmy.mySoldiers.$.stamina': staminaToSet,
                        'myArmy.mySoldiers.$.moral'  : moralToSet
                    }
                }
```

This gave me the result i wanted, before i accidentally inserted the condition query with the update one...