# Query by two params with $and in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a user model like this:

```
  user : {
       myArmy : {
           mySoldiers : [
               {
                    positioned : false,
                    soldierInfo : {
                       _id : s99212
                    }
               },
               {
                    positioned : true,
                    soldierInfo : {
                       _id : s99112
                    }
               }
           ]
       }
   },
   user : {
       myArmy : {
           mySoldiers : [
               {
                    positioned : true,
                    soldierInfo : {
                       _id : s99212
                    }
               },
               {
                    positioned : false,
                    soldierInfo : {
                       _id : s99112
                    }
               }
           ]
       }
   }

   ...
```

I have a query that i want to do to return the user(s) who have soldier id s99212 positioned (true): (could be thousands of those, and i need to read and retrieve them all)

This is my faulty query with mongoose:

```
var soldierId = s99212;


stream = User.find({
            $and: [
                {'myArmy.mySoldier.positioned': {$ne: null}},
                {'myArmy.mySoldier.soldierInfo._id': soldierId}
            ]
        }).lean(true).stream();
```

Nothing is returned by this query, should there be another way to do this $and stuff?

How exactly am i suppose to use $elemMatch if at all, should it be instead of the find? (If it worth to mention, i want to return the complete user object, not just parts of it...)

Tried this, crashed my app:

```
    stream = User.find({
        '$elemMatch': [
            {'myArmy.mySoldiers.pos': {$ne: null}},
            {'myArmy.mySoldiers.soldierInfo._id': soldierId}
        ]
    }).lean(true).stream();
```

I know i have a small syntax problem, where is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection). Answers using `$elemMatch` in the query as both conditions need to be applied to the same array element. That is what `$elemMatch` does.

Comment: I dont think $elemMatch should be in my case, i need the full user object if soldier id is positioned by this structure, would you mind set me straight?

Comment: You are reading the wrong answer. Look at [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) in the documentation and then look at the answers again. Remember that "you" are the person asking for the advice of those who know better. `$elemMatch` is what you need here to match both properties on an element. Does not alter the object in any way.

Comment: Yes but again, this small syntax problem is a killer for me, what is the correct way to write it down?   i tried this one: stream = User.find(
            {'$elemMatch': {'myClub.myPlayers.player._id': ev.outcome.playerId,'myClub.myPlayers.pos':{ $ne: null } } }
        ).lean(true).stream();         and failed again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple and well documented. The [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator acts as a "query in itself", where it applies "it's conditions" to members of the array specified:

```js
var query = User.find({
    "myArmy.mySoldiers": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "positioned": { "$ne": null },
            "soldierInfo._id": soldierId
        }
    }
});
```

Therefore for a document to "match" then the conditions specfied under `$elemMatch` must be present and valid for the "same" array element. Array on "left", arguments on "right".

Other "dot notation" forms **only** ever test that the values match "some element" in the array, and not necessarily the same one.

Comment: I love you! i just forgot those: myArmy.mySoldiers,

Comment: @totothegreat How about going back to and having a "red hot go" at your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32433412/5031275). Now you got a bit more insight into syntax it should be simple to work out. Or at least get "part" of the way along.

Comment: You are right, now part 2 begins, give me a few im gonna build another army just for you